# Two-persons keyboard-only racing game for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, game

I am looking for a racing game (Tuxracer-like/MarioKart-like/cars/bikes/boats/planes/anything) that is available for Ubuntu Linux, for 2 (or more) simultaneous players.

I don't have any joystick or mouse or anything, I just have one keyboard. So the game has to be controlled by both players using the same keyboard (for instance one player uses keys ADWS and one player uses keys JLIK, or similar).

Emulators OK as long as everything is legal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can play **[SuperTuxKart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperTuxKart)** in split screen mode, each player using a different set of keys from the keyboard.

[image: SuperTuxKart Game Screenshot]

Be careful with the keys, though, there might be conflicts. It is always better to use two different keyboards (in addition to different keys).

Comment: (For information on key conflicts, look at n-Key Rollover and Keyboard Ghosting)

Comment: Could you add a screenshot and / or elaborate a bit about the gameplay of this?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer Added a screenshots, but from the original question I gather the person asking is not looking for further details. The screenshot and the name of the game itself already give hints enough about its gameplay.

Comment: @Gallaecio it does not matter whether people are asking for further details. For high-quality site - for others than person asking the original question - more than links are required. Please see [this meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/86/youre-doing-it-all-wrong).