# Linux game with hotseat multiplayer

Tags: game

I'm looking for games which run on Linux and support a hotseat multiplayer. I'm basically looking for a game to play with my friends from the university. I don't care about the hardware requirements, but

1. I prefer a native Linux game to a Windows game running under Wine
2. I prefer FOSS to closed source
3. Local multiplayer: [Hotseat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotseat_%28multiplayer_mode%29) mode (playing on the same device)

Games are software, and have been shown to be on-topic [here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/would-video-game-related-question-be-ontopic).

Comment: Not exactly duplicate, but look at those questions: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/255/6957, http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/826/6957

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to play turn-based strategy games (TBS), most of them have hotseat multiplayer. *Heroes of Might and Magic III*, as I remember, was ported to Linux -- though you will be limited to only the first version, no addons (if I am not mistaken). Anyway, the Windows version works well under Wine even on Asus EeePC series laptops.

If you decide to play under Wine, definitely try *Heroes of Might and Magic IV*, for many reasons its balance is objectively more **diverse** than in *HoMM III*, more like that of *HoMM II*, and far less rules are needed to make gameplay more fair.
For example, *HoMM IV* tournaments usually only ban one thing, one hero class (the Thief), and it is actually allowed on the smaller maps sometimes. For *HoMM III* the tournament lists of prohibited options take pages and pages, because too many options allow you to break the game.

Another good TBS to try is *Age of Wonders* series. My favourite is the first one, made back in 1999, but you might prefer some other one, so try them all. The first game runs perfectly under Wine, *Age of Wonders III* has native Linux support, and I have no information about the second game in the series.

Comment: [The Battle for Wesnoth](https://www.wesnoth.org/) is a open source game inspired by Heroes of Might and Magic and looks pretty good.

Answer (score -1):

[Hedgewars](https://www.hedgewars.org) is a worms clone that fits the bill